# Chess movement, running out of memory python loops

Tags: python, loops, chess

I was tasked with calculating all the potential positions a knight can take, when starting at (0,0). I am a beginner so my code is clunky, but it seems to work for a smaller set of iterations. As soon as I get 8-9 steps deep, I run out of memory.

```
def moves(pos):
    re=[[]]
    for i in range(0,len(pos)):
        x,y=pos[i]
        a=[x+2,y+1]
        b=[x+2,y-1]
        c=[x-2,y+1]
        d=[x-2,y-1]
        e=[x+1,y+2]
        f=[x+1,y-2]
        g=[x-1,y+2]
        h=[x-1,y-2]
        re.append(a)
        re.append(b)
        re.append(c)
        re.append(d)
        re.append(e)
        re.append(f)
        re.append(g)
        re.append(h)
    del re[0]
    return re
def clean(a):
    cmoves=[]
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        if a[i][0]>-1 and a[i][1]>-1 and a[i][0]<9 and a[i][1]<9 :
            cmoves.append(a[i])
    return cmoves 
def comb(a):
   return clean(moves(a))
pos= [[0,0]]  
a=comb(res)
steps_count=10
for step in range(steps_count):
    res=comb(res)
```

Any help or tip is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In `clean`, also remove duplicate positions. You can use a `set` to keep track of which positions you've seen before, if you convert the coordinates to use `tuple`s instead of `list`s.

Comment: Afaik, I need the know which positions come up how often, if I want to calculate something like average distance. So if I would delete duplicates, I would lose that information I think ?

Comment: @hmmmbob You can keep track of your positions using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead then.

Comment: @hmmmbob, consider two locations, a starting square A and a nearby destination B. You are repeatedly adding B (as reachable from A), and repeatedly adding A (as reachable from B). It's hard to see how that would be useful. Assign the starting square distance zero and its eight nearby squares distance 1. Then assign greater distances to additional squares, without ever changing an already-recorded distance. Then you shall have "shortest path distance" from origin to a large number of reachable squares.